# How can i generate custom webfont icons?

Tags: icons, webfonts

I upload a sample pic. 
My question is, that how can i generate icons like that?  Or these are painted by a designer?

Font awesome doesnt have to much icons like that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

More than one question here...

Q: How can i generate custom webfont icons?

A: Using font desing software. Take a look for search result in google "font editing tool". I've use fontforge for this, with good results.

Q: how can i generate icons like that?

A: You can create them with a vectorial graphics editor, like "inkscape" for example and inport them into a glyph of your new font... or build them directly with the font editing software.

Q: these are painted by a designer?

A: In general "design" is made by a designer, that's why the look good... anybody can paint an icon, but getting good results is not that easy.

There are plenty of free icon fonts for web, sure you could find something more close to your needs than fontawesome. If not, you can build your own one with fontforge, but this can be a lot of hard work.